# Google Glass: disable turn on while it's charging

Tags: android

The google support website says :

Turn off Glass while it's charging
Charging Glass automatically turns on the device, even if it was powered off before plugging in. To power down while charging, press the power button for 3 seconds. You'll know it's still charging if the LED light pulsates.

Is there a way to programatically disable this auto turn on while it's charging?